# early bound entity classes dynamics CRM 2011, Error while updating or deleting

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

i create the CrmProxy class using CrmScUtil now when i am trying to use it i got some problems.

Creating a contact works fine, but updating and deleting just throws this error:

{"An error occured while processing this request."}

at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges()

Could you please let me know what am i doing wrong?, the query works it returns the contact data that i am trying to update/delete.

OrganizationServiceProxy orgserv;
            orgserv = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgConfigInfo, clientCreds);
            orgserv.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());

```
        //Create            
        using (var context = new XrmContext(orgserv))
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact()
            {
                FirstName = "fName",
                LastName = "lName",
                Address1_Line1 = "Address1_Line1",
                Address1_City = "Address1_City",
                Address1_StateOrProvince = "XX",
                Address1_PostalCode = "00000",
                Telephone1 = "(000) 000-0000",
                JobTitle = "JobTitle",
                Company = "Company",
                EMailAddress1 = "test@test.com"
            };
            context.AddObject(contact);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        //End Create

        //Update
        using (var contextUpdate = new XrmContext(orgserv))
        {
            try
            {
                Contact con = contextUpdate.ContactSet.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EMailAddress1 == "test@test.com");
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Fax = "Fax132456";
                    contextUpdate.UpdateObject(con);
                    contextUpdate.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        //End Update


        //Delete
        using (var contextDelete = new XrmContext(orgserv))
        {
            Contact con = contextDelete.ContactSet.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EMailAddress1 == "test@test.com");
            if (con != null)
            {
                contextDelete.DeleteObject(con);
                contextDelete.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        //End Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer for this, i hope this helps:

it looks like there is a bug on the latest CoreAssamblies (7.1.0)

So the key is uninstall the NuGet package and install 7.0.0

Install-Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies -Version 7.0.0

After that works with no issues.